# Copy/pasting through double click events

Tags: excel, double-click, vba

I have a double click event where I want it to hold the copy of a certain range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A25, A29:A34, A36:A40, F3:F14, F18:F21, F25:F26, F3:F32, F36:F37, K3:K22, K26:K40, P3:P22")) Is Nothing Then
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
    End If
End Sub
```

When I click on one of the ranges, I can see the copy highlight come around quickly and disappear.  How do I hold this to clipboard?  Ideally I'd like to be able to paste this range on the next double click event as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, _
Range("A3:A25, A29:A34, A36:A40, F3:F14, F18:F21, F25:F26, F3:F32, F36:F37, K3:K22, K26:K40, P3:P22")) Is Nothing Then
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Select
End If
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

I've tested it and it works. :D

**Edit1:** This also works

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = False
If Not Intersect(Target, _
Range("A3:A25, A29:A34, A36:A40, F3:F14, F18:F21, F25:F26, F3:F32, F36:F37, K3:K22, K26:K40, P3:P22")) Is Nothing Then
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
Else
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: +1) `Ideally I'd like to be able to paste this range on the next double click event as well.` - you could also check `Application.CutCopyMode` and if it's already = `xlCopy` then paste values

Comment: That's a winner!  Thanks guys.  I wonder why it doesn't hold it with Range.Copy though?

Comment: because when you double click you access the cell and that overwrites the `Range.Copy`. so what you need to do is `Cancel` the double click. see my edit :D